# Ray Tracing calculation in C

Tags: c, raytracing

I'm new to ray tracing and trying to program one in C. But My program keep on showing a dot (around 1-3 pixel) of the sphere in the wrong places and now I'm confused. This feels like a very stupid question, but I'm confused about exactly how big is 1 radius of a sphere? What I mean by that is if the radius is 1, the circle is 2 pixels?

I know all the calculations and I triple checked if I had any errors in my codes. but just incase, here is part of my codes:

Directions:

```
//size: 1024x768, view point (512 384 1), screen (0 0 0) to (1024 768 0)
ray[0] = x - start_x;
ray[1] = y - start_y;
ray[2] = 0 - start_z;
//normalize
double length;
length = (sqrt((ray[0]*ray[0]) + (ray[1]*ray[1]) + (ray[2]*ray[2])));
ray[0] = ray[0]/length;
ray[1] = ray[1]/length;
ray[2] = ray[2]/length;
```

Intersection:

```
temp = top; //my struct with sphere data, _x, _y, _z, _r, _red, _green, _blue
//x and y is the current pixel value
while (temp != NULL) {
  x_diff = start_x - temp->_x + 0.0;
  y_diff = start_y - temp->_y + 0.0;
  z_diff = start_z - temp->_z + 0.0;
  //a = 1 because my direction is a normalized
  b = 2.0 * ((rayVector[0] * x_diff) + (rayVector[1] * y_diff) + (rayVector[2] * z_diff));
  c = (x_diff * x_diff * 1.0) + (y_diff * y_diff) + (z_diff * z_diff) - (temp->_r * temp->_r);

  check = (b * b) - (4.0 * c);
  if (check < 0) { //0
     pixels[width][height][0] = 0.0;
     pixels[width][height][1] = 0.0;
     pixels[width][height][2] = 0.0;
  }
  else if (check == 0) { //1
     r1 = (b * -1.0) /2.0;
     if (r1 < nearest_z) {
        nearest_z = r1;
        pixels[width][height][0] = temp->_red;
        pixels[width][height][1] = temp->_green;
        pixels[width][height][2] = temp->_blue;
     }
  }
  else { //2
     r1 = ((b * -1.0) + sqrt(check))/2.0;
     r2 = ((b * -1.0) - sqrt(check))/2.0;
     if ((r1 < r2) && (r1 < nearest_z)) {
        nearest_z = r1;
        pixels[width][height][0] = 255.0;
        pixels[width][height][1] = 0;
        pixels[width][height][2] = 0;
     }
     else if ((r2 < r1) && (r2 < nearest_z)) {
        nearest_z = r2;
        pixels[width][height][0] = temp->_red;
        pixels[width][height][1] = temp->_green;
        pixels[width][height][2] = temp->_blue;
     }
  }
  temp = temp->next;
}
```

I haven't done any lightings yet since the flat colouring it doesn't work. I'm new to openGL so expect me to miss some common functions in the codes. Thanks in advance.

Edit: 
I only have one sphere currently, but my output looks like: [img1](http://i.imgur.com/SplsPpv.png)

I was expecting a bigger circle? Also, I had a printf for each intersection (if there is) and when I manually plot in a paper, it is a 4x5 pixel square. But there are 4 dots in the output.

Edit 2: I change the size of the sphere to: x = 512 y = 384 z = -21 r = 30, it gave me this:
[img2](http://i.imgur.com/Ez9fo7T.png)
Again, I only have one sphere and there are 4 in the image. Also, there are holds between the lines?

If I change the z value to -20, now my output is all white (colour of sphere).
I use `glDrawPixels(1024,768,GL_RGB,GL_FLOAT,pixels);` to draw

I had a RBG output file, everything seems to be in the right place. but when I draw on the program, it is off.

Comment: Sounds like aliasing problems. However, this question really needs images (just provide imgur link, someone will hopefully edit it in, if you don't have permission to add images with your current reputation), now it is a bit unclear what the actual problem really is.

Comment: But if you just ask what ["radius"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius) means, then the radius of a circle or a sphere is the distance from center to the edge. It's half of the diameter.

Comment: In pure geometry a line does not have any thickness, but we have to draw one with a minimum thickness of 1 pixel. Similarly the diameter of a circle of radius 1 will have 3 pixels: one at the centre and 1 at each of the extremes of radius. In early Mac systems this was got round by having coordinate positions theoretically lieing *between* pixel positions.

Comment: Ah, this make sense. I just need to increase my radius. Thanks

Comment: Could `ray[0]*ray[0]` overflow?  What type is used? If type `int`, what size `int`?